# From typescript to browser build steps

Tags: typescript, browserify, typescript-typings, tsc

I'm experimenting with introducing typescript to an existing web application (*angular 1*). Starting with typescript there are a lot of concepts to grasp.

---

**My question is, what are steps to run typescript code in html with external modules? Should I transpile definition files or is there a general solution?**

What i currently know:

1. have `tsconfig.json` file (*with commonjs as a module loader*)
2. have `index.ts` file (*with external module import*)
3. have `./node_modules/@types/angular` folder (*with types definition*)
4. run `tsc`
5. run `browserify` **-> problem here, Cannot find module '@types/angular'**
6. include generated file to `index.html`

---

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "listFiles": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

`index.ts`

```
import * as angular from "@types/angular"

const app = angular.module('app', []);
```